# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              bool validated = formKey.currentState!.validate();
              if (validated) {
                formKey.currentState!.save();
                final Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    Map<String, dynamic>.from(formKey.currentState!.value);
                data['date'] =
                    (data['date'] as DateTime).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
                
                await eventDBS.create(data);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
```

When i click on the button occur the error "Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast" and the currentState shows error without the null check(!), i don't know what to do, i really appreciate any help

Comment: `data['date']` is `null`, which probably means it's not in the `Map`.  Check first or use null-aware operators (e.g. `data['date'] = data['data']?.millisecondsSinceEpoch ?? 0;`)

Comment: i might do it wrong but not work, the receiver can'tbe null,so the null-aware is unnecessary

Comment: Maybe needs to be `data['date'] = (data['data']?.millisecondsSinceEpoch) ?? 0;`. (Sorry, I can't check it myself right now.)

Comment: Thank you, you really saved me. now that's an error with firestore but i think i can handle it.